# File (file descriptor 3) exists but can not open it by fopen php

Tags: php, linux, fopen, file-descriptor

I'm trying to get stream from file descriptor 3 by PHP

The problem is i can not open file in spite of the file exists

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$file = fopen('/proc/12916/fd/3' ,'r');
if($file == NULL) print_r("NULL");

?>
```

I take file name manually and pass it to fopen function.
After executed I got this message:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(/proc/12916/fd/3): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /root/test.php on line 4

Despite of that file exist

```
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/12916/fd/3 
lr-x------ 1 root asterisk 64 7月  4 18:15 /proc/12916/fd/3 -> pipe:[90140090]
```

The point is in an existing official php library doing the same thing like me, is also using fopen for opening fd3. And it got fail. 
I'm so confusing here.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct Access Rights to read the file ?
It seems only the "root" user has the rights.

Maybe you should do a `chmod 644` on the file.

Comment: I did. i granted it to 777 with all permissions before but it still got  the same result